# Issue CORS preflight request with credentials

Tags: lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am using serverless yml template to deploy my functions to aws. The following snippet show the configuration for one of the endpoints,

```
functions:
  publish:
    handler: lambda.publish
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: publish
          cors:
            origin: ${self:custom.origin.${self:custom.stage}}
            allowCredentials: true
```

This is my fetch request,

```
fetch(`${SOME_DOMAIN}/publish`, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
```

I am handling response headers in my lambda like this,

```
const ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
  'http://localhost:3001',
  'https://staging.company.com.au',
  'https://blaze-staging.company.com.au',
  'https://www.company.com.au',
  'https://blaze.company.com.au',
  'https://direct.company.com.au',
]

const origin = event.headers.origin
let headers

if (ALLOWED_ORIGINS.includes(origin)) {
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
  }
} else {
  headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3001',
  }
}

const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers,
  body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Successfully published the message.' }),
}

callback(null, response)
```

I am not able to get the pre-flight requests to work as I cannot set multiple origins. How to get around this problem? setting `mode: 'no-cors'`
on the request is actually allowing requests from any domain. Any help is much appreciated.

Following error will be displayed for the pre-flight request:

> Failed to load https://o9a0130i2r.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/development/publish:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://direct.company.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response
>   serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
>   resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50459481/edit to edit/update your question & add the exact error message that you’re seeing in browser devtools when things aren’t working as you’d expect. What do you mean by “set multiple origins”? How’s that different than what you’re already doing with your existing `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin` code? That sets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response-header value to the same value as the Origin request header — if the origin’s an allowed origin — right? Are you saying that code’s not working?

Comment: @sideshowbarker There is no problem with `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin`. Problem is with pre-flight request which doesn't hit the lambda it is handled by the api-gateway. I am not sure how to pass that through. I have added the error message

Comment: @sideshowbarker Regarding "setting multiple origins" I am talking about the serverless template. You need this for the pre-flight request to make it through. I want the request with credentials to be supported from multiple domains.

Comment: Have you read the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html? That seems to show exactly how to enable support for OPTIONS requests in AWS API Gateway. The cause of the error message you cite in the question appears to be that your server is responding to the OPTIONS request with a 403 because you’ve not enabled support in it for OPTIONS requests.

Comment: I am using serverless to deploy my lambdas. I am following this guide - https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/. So need help with respect to serverless framework. If I am creating the API by myself I can solve this problem.

Comment: I am in the same situation, I have enabled CORS in the API Gateway side, there's an OPTIONS method with the appropiate headers/response in place, I'm returning the appropiate headers from my request... And the request fails in the pre-flight request :(

Comment: @CarlosMartinez I have solved this issue by creating a options endpoint on the gateway and followed the same setup as shown in the above code snippets. Not sure if this helps you, if you want any help please let me know.

Comment: Hi @Mah3ndra. Im facing the same problem. Could u elaborate on what u did to fix the options request failing? My existing lambda code is quite similar to your example above already.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Dan I have posted the answer. Please let me know if you still face any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional endpoint to the same lambda that is handling the post request.

Something like this to `serverless.yml`

```
  options:
    handler: lambda.options
    events:
      - http:
          method: options
          path: publish
```

You can add your origins to the allowed origins list

```
export const options = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3001',
  ]

  const origin = event.headers.origin || event.headers.Origin
  let response

  if (ALLOWED_ORIGINS.includes(origin)) {
    response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Success' }),
    }
  } else {
    response = {
      statusCode: 403,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: {
        error: 'Missing Authentication token',
        origin: `Request origin is ${origin}`,
      },
      }),
    }
  }

  callback(null, response)
  return
}
```

Now, when the options request is made by the browser then this method we handle it and return 200 if it is from the allowed origin or an error. You can customize the error message according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for posting that @Mah3ndra.  I also got it working thismorning using a custom response mapping template in apigateway.
I didnt think about creating a seperate lambda to handle the options request. it is probably a quicker option than what i did lol.

Comment: @Dan Would it be possible for you to share me the serverless.yml where you setup the apigateway? I've had the same issue and also have them run in local. Thanks in advance!